# contenteditable="true"のdiv要素内で、HTMLタグを含めて選択範囲の文字列を取得したい

Tags: javascript

↓確認しました。
[getselection contenteditable 特定のdiv内でユーザーが選択した範囲を取得する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69756/getselection-contenteditable-%e7%89%b9%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%aediv%e5%86%85%e3%81%a7%e3%83%a6%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b6%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e9%81%b8%e6%8a%9e%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e7%af%84%e5%9b%b2%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)

下記のようにrange.toString()で選択範囲の文字列を取得できたのですが、HTMLタグも含めて取得するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

```js
function onSelectionChange() {
let selection = window.getSelection();
if(selection.rangeCount != 1) {
    return;
}

const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

if(!range.collapsed){
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = range.toString();
}

}

document.addEventListener('selectionchange', onSelectionChange);
onSelectionChange();
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="text" contenteditable="true"><b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i></div>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents()` で `DocumentFragment` ノードが得られます。その子ノードをループして、`Element` だったら `outerHTML` を呼ぶ、`Text` だったら `<` と `&` をエスケープ、のようにシリアライズしてください。

`new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents())` という手もありますが、こちらは XML としてシリアライズするので `xmlns` がついたりします。

---

> > もし ol が選択されてたら
>
> はい、`<b>ol</b>`で取得したいです。

選択範囲を `document.execCommand('copy', ...)` でクリップボードにコピーして、[Clipboard API で読み出す](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/read)という手法が可能かもしれません。
[【JavaScript】クリップボードの内容を読み取る方法](https://webfrontend.ninja/js-clipboard-read/)
読み取る方法はこのページが参考になるかもしれません。

コピーしたくない場合は、簡単な方法はなさそうです。`getSelection().getRangeAt(0)` で得られた `Range` オブジェクトの始点と終点の情報から必要なタグやテキストを自力で判定してHTMLソースを組み立てます。そういうことをしてくれるライブラリなどが存在するかもしれませんね。

Comment: 前者の方法で試してみました。
全体を選択した場合、うまくタグも返してくれるようなのですが、
"bold"を選択した場合、なぜかタグが抜けてしまいます。。

Comment: 選択範囲にタグが入らないのでそれは想定内です。もし `ol` が選択されてたら `<div><b>ol</b></div>` になって欲しいのですか

Comment: はい、<b>ol</b>で取得したいです。
getSelection()では難しいでしょうか？

Comment: 回答を更新してみました。